# Why the boolean of InvokeRequired and Dispatcher.CheckAccess inverted?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, invoke, dispatcher

I am converting a VB Form code that uses `InvokeRequired` to C# WPF

```
// VB
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
   MessageBox.Show("Apple")
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Orange")
End If
```

The VB code returns "**Apple**"

```
// C#
if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
   MessageBox.Show("Apple");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Orange");
}
```

But my C# code return "**Orange**"

Isn't C#'s `CheckAccess` same as VB Formc's`InvokeRequired`? Why the boolean is inverted?

Comment: The WPF guy didn't talk to the Winforms guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` checks if you ARE associated with the thread, in our case its false.

`InvokeRequired` checks if you NEED to be associated with the thread, in our case its true.

You need to invoke (`InvokeRequired == true`) when you're not associated with the specific thread. In other words, logical definition of invoke required would be:

```
InvokeRequired = !Dispatcher.CheckAccess()
```

Invoke is required if you do not have access to the specific thread

Comment: Did not this answer the question or did i misinterpret it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's saying that `InvokeRequired` means you need to invoke onto the GUI thread whereas `CheckAccess` is checking whether the current thread has access to the GUI and will return `true` if it does have access.

It does seem a bit confusing to change the naming this way.

**NB**. C# has a `InvokeRequired` property for `Windows.Forms`

Comment: CheckAccess is false when the thread cannot access main UI thread, and InvokeRequired is true when thread cannot access main UI thread and need Invoke? So the boolean of CheckAccess and InvokeRequired is indeed opposite? The MSDN is really confusing me..

Comment: Well, you could always create a property called `InvokeRequired` which called the `CheckAccess( )` function and inverted the result!?